# Python for upward trend pattern recognition of time series data

Tags: python, time-series

I have a time series data set, where I like to catch an upward trending pattern (normally the climbing trend is 30-90 days long) in the history. 
I have tried to use rolling window, but I have to drop NaN to get linear regression work, which messes the x- axis, and hence the regression coefficients.

My Questions are:

1. What is the best way to recognize the upward pattern for time series
   data?
2. If my approach (rolling window linear regression) is on the right direction, how do I solve the NaN problem, which can cause an empty return for the linear fit or mess the scale of x-axis?
3. If I like to choose multiple windows, instead of rolling window to apply the linear regression, how do I approach?

Thank you for your help!

Dataframe example

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np

dict_ = {'COMPLETIONDATE': ['2017-10-05 11:05:08',
  '2017-10-06 14:18:25',
  '2017-10-05 10:52:20',
  '2017-10-05 11:13:18',
  '2017-10-03 15:18:08',
  '2017-10-06 11:19:38',
  '2017-10-03 15:36:34',
  '2017-10-06 11:32:08',
  '2017-10-05 11:15:38',
  '2017-10-06 11:20:37'],
 'LOGFIELD16': [45.44571,
  46.31465,
  47.66407,
  38.89286,
  45.37415,
  38.44305,
  45.74217,
  40.59497,
  39.72602,
  46.18687]}

df_ = pd.DataFrame(dict_)

    COMPLETIONDATE  LOGFIELD16
0   2017-10-05 11:05:08 45.44571
1   2017-10-06 14:18:25 46.31465
2   2017-10-05 10:52:20 47.66407
3   2017-10-05 11:13:18 38.89286
4   2017-10-03 15:18:08 45.37415
5   2017-10-06 11:19:38 38.44305
6   2017-10-03 15:36:34 45.74217
7   2017-10-06 11:32:08 40.59497
8   2017-10-05 11:15:38 39.72602
9   2017-10-06 11:20:37 46.18687
```

Time series plot
[image]

My current approach is rolling window linear regression, and then detect slope above the threshold. But challenge is how to fit linear regression for the chosen window of data given possibly missing data on some days in that window.

```
# function to calculate the slope
def roll_reg(df):
    df_size = df.shape[0]
    linregress = scipy.stats.linregress(df, np.array(range(df_size)))
    return linregress[0]

df_.index = pd.to_datetime(df_.COMPLETIONDATE)
df_.sort_index(inplace=True)    

df_[['LOGFIELD16']].resample("1D").mean().dropna().rolling(30).apply(roll_reg).plot(style='o')
```

Plot of rolling regression slope. However, if you look closer, the values of the slope plateau around 2 which is not what is supposed to be.

[image]

Comment: Use [time-aware rolling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#time-aware-rolling): `.rolling('30D')`

Comment: @Goyo "TypeError: an integer is required"